# Can't get Ubuntu to ping by name

Tags: networking

So I have a machine with server 2012 acting as a domain controller and a dns server.  I have another server 2012 machine running as a hyper-v host for a handful of ubuntu 15.04 vms.

From either server and from my workstation I can successfully ping every other windows machine and the ubuntu machines by name or by ip.

From the ubuntu vms I can successfully ping any windows box by name or by ip.

The ubuntu machines will successfully ping each other by IP, but not by name.  I really need them to be able to resolve each others names and I can't figure it out.